# What are the best practices to create a user assigned managed identity for an Azure resource?

Tags: azure-managed-identity

Should we create one user assigned identity for all the services that a resource access or should we create one for each service the resource access?

Example: My WebApp needs access to a `eventhub`, `servicebus`, `storageContainer` etc. Should I create  three identities (`user_assigned_eventhub`, `user_assigned_servicebus`, `user_Assigned_storage`) one for each service or create one (`user_assigned_webApp`) and access all services using this identity?

Answer (score 0):

> create one (user_assigned_webApp) and access all services using this identity

This is correct, you just need to create one user-assigned identity, then in your sample, navigate to the web app in the portal -> `Identity` -> `User assigned` -> add it to your web app, then you can use this MSI(managed identity) to access other resources. When using MSI to access other resources, the MSI is used to represent the client, the resource side does not need it, so you don't need to create MSI for them.

Comment: we are creating one per service the resource accesses per security reasons, as in if one identity is compromised only the service for which the id has been granted permissions will be affected, there by reducing the risk.

Comment: @Mounika It is really unnecessary, first you need to know the usage of the MSI(managed identity), it is used to access resources from an Azure Environment supported MSI, you just need to create the MSI for the client(in your case web app), means if you create MSI for the resource side e.g. azure storage, it is not used to access any other resources, so it is useless.

Comment: @Mounika Any other concerns about this issue?